# Is there C# look-alike for Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, compiler-construction

Is there C# look-alike for Linux? What about a compiler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is another language called [Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala). It's not well known, but as you can see from the page, an interesting amount of projects have been produced already.

Answer (score 48):

You could actually use C# with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/).

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use Mono, I think Java may be your closest alternative.

Comment: Did someone hit you with a Java stick three days ago...:)

Comment: you may want to reword your answer then, because it looks like you're saying that not using mono is a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Look-alike? I am assuming you mean a similar language? You could always just use C# with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), a multi-platform port of the .Net framework

Answer (score 4):

Mono is the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I found that going from Java to C# was very easy.  Maybe you could try working with Java?  Of course you'd have to learn a whole new set of libraries, so there's a learning curve, but the languages felt pretty similar as I recall (it's been a while)

Answer (score 1):

You could always use [Boo DSL](http://boo.codehaus.org/) on Mono to construct a C# clone. But then again it would probably be easier to use C# directly on Mono itself I guess ;)